# Maven can't find gwt-test-util.properties

Tags: unit-testing, maven, gwt, gwt-test-utils

im building a web-application with GWT and Maven. For the unit-tests, i'm using the gwt-test-utils Framework.

I tried it as described in the tutorial (https://github.com/gwt-test-utils/gwt-test-utils/wiki/Unit-testing-basics).

When i run my unit tests in eclipse, all works fine. (The "gwt-test-utils.properties" file is at "test/META-INF/gwt-test-utils.properties")

But if i'm try to run the tests with maven, the test failes because it cant find the "gwt-test-utils.properties" file in the META-INF folder.

Do I need to explizit specify this folder/file in Maven?

**Edit:**

I solved it by my self. I had to add the "test" directory to the "resources", too.

```
<testSourceDirectory>test</testSourceDirectory>
  <testResources>
    <testResource>
      <directory>test</directory>
  </testResource>
</testResources>
```

Now it works..